# How to intercept a Tab key in edit control

Tags: .net, winforms, key

I need custom behavior for tab keys in RichTextEdit control.

Currenty the best I have is this:

```
editBox.PreviewKeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(this.field_PreviewKeyPress);


  private void field_PreviewKeyPress(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Tab: 
                     //Some code here
                break;
            }
        }
```

The tab key is registered fine, but after that the control processes the key anyway and moves the focus to next control. There seems no way to consume this key event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution myself - override bool RichTextEdit.ProcessCmdKey(ref Message m, Keys keyData).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this CodeProject article could give you some hint:

[TabKeyIntercept - Intercept and process the Tab key in a Windows.Forms form](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/TabKeyIntercept.aspx)

> [...] Fortunately, in the base Form class,
>   there exists the `protected override bool ProcessTabKey(bool forward)`
>   method. Using this method, we can
>   intercept and "consume" the Tab key.
>
> And, as it turns out, if the
>   `ProcessTabKey()` method's return value
>   is false, the Tab key does make it
>   into the OnKeyDown() method. But, of
>   course, if your code "consumes" the
>   Tab key in the `ProcessTabKey()` method,
>   you probably won't need to process it
>   in the `OnKeyDown()` method.
>
> Also, the Control-Tab combination
>   makes it into the `OnKeyDown()` method.
>
> So, knowing these things, we are
>   prepared to define a customized use
>   for the Tab key -- and we can code the
>   form to allow the user to use the
>   Control-Tab combination to toggle
>   between the normal use/meaning of the
>   Tab key and our custom use.

Comment: ProcessTabKey is Form method. It would be very clumsy to have a custom form, just to alter behavior of one field .

Answer (score 0):

You say you're using a "RichTextEdit" control but I guess you mean RichTextBox. If so, you should be able to set the [AcceptsTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.acceptstab.aspx) property to True to allow it to process the tab key.

Comment: Really? How interesting! I'll leave the answer here so that others who read it can see your comment and learn why it's *not* the answer.